# React Native, whats mean about three point in '...this'

Tags: react-native

code below is a piece in demo of React Native
   my doubt is that whats meaning of '...this' in this piece code
   thanks

```
render: function() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View
              style={styles.center}
              {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
            >
              <Text>Like</Text>
              <Text>You selected: {this.state.selected}</Text>
              <Animated.View 
                style={[styles.likeContainer, this.getLikeContainerStyle()]}
              >
                <View style={styles.borderContainer} />
                <View style={styles.imgContainer}>
                  {this.getImages()}
                </View>
              </Animated.View>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this fantastic example if you want to get a handle on ... operator. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html

If you don't know what props will be passed to the component, you can use spread attribute. The three dots `...` is called as spread operator in JSX.

The `...` operator (or spread operator) is already supported for arrays in ES6. There is also an ECMAScript proposal for Object Rest and Spread Properties. You can take advantage of this and pass props without explicitly writing them.

Answer (score 0):

All the properties of panHandlers are passed as props to the View. `...` is called the spread operator.

"The spread operator allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) are expected."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 0):

The `...` is the new ES6 Spread Operator feature used to substitute for multiple array arguments. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

A better use case of spread operator in `react` is to pass all the values in `panHandlers` array, as in your code as props